# My egg roll wraps smell sour. They expire in 2 days. Are they still okay to use?

Tags: eggs, rolls

I'm cooking egg rolls and my egg roll wraps **smell sour**. They say they expire in 2 days. Are they still okay to use?

Comment: noodle dough smelling sour is not a good sign.  I personally wouldn't use them.  (and there are lots of questionable things that I will typically eat).  Had the package been opened?  (that'll throw off any dates stamped on it ... as will improper handling (eg, someone leaving it in their shopping cart for an hour, then putting it back when they changed their mind)

Comment: That's an answer I'd upvote @Joe

Comment: Ingredients that do not smell right or appear to have 'gone off' should be binned!

Answer (score 8):

The dates provided on packaging are not precise. They make excellent guides but too many factors can alter the timeline (as mentioned by @Joe, being mishandled in the market or being previously opened among other things).

As a general rule, if something smells unusual and off, **it probably is**. I would personally throw them out.